# Manage archive logs on DBCS

Tags: oracle, backup

We are testing an Oracle OCI DBCS and I have enabled automatic backup. I saw that the archive logs have been accumulating since I enabled automatic backup and I would like to know if OCI also deletes the archive logs automatically?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling the automatic backup configures the following archivelog deletion policy:

```
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY TO BACKED UP 1 TIMES TO 'SBT_TAPE';
```

Archivelogs that are already backed up will be automatically deleted when usage of fast recovery area reaches a certain threshold (80%).